# Serialize ArrayList to String and Deserialize the String to ArrayList the constraint is the array list contains any characters in the characterset

Tags: java

I do serialize in the below code and correct the code for serialize and deserialize how to do this? we dont want any split delimiter because the List may contain any character so there is no possibility to string split

```
 public class ArratListSerializaationTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            dataList.add("A");
            dataList.add(",");
            dataList.add("B");
            String datStr = serialize(dataList);
            List<String> receivedList = deserialize(datStr);
        }

        public static String serialize(List<String> dataList){

            StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder("[");
            dataList.forEach((data) -> {
                dataBuilder.append(data);
            });
            return dataBuilder.append("]").toString();
        }

        public static List<String> deserialize(String dataStr){

             ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();      
             //TODO
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since there is no separator, there is no way to distinguish string tokens you have concatenated with `append` .

Comment: Yes that is the problem from client side if put delimiter the delimiter may it self an element in the List of strings

Comment: Try using XML...

Comment: How, can you suggest any link and the constraint is we should do this only in java without using any third party lib

Answer (score 2):

Finally I give solution like this so my problem solved

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class SerializeDeSerializeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add("A");
        dataList.add(",");
        dataList.add("B");
        System.out.println("Before Serialization\n");
        print(dataList);
        String datStr = serialize(dataList);
        List<String> receivedList = deserialize(datStr);
        System.out.println("\nAfter DeSerialization\n");
        print(receivedList);
    }
    public static void print(List<String> dataList){

        dataList.forEach((data) -> {
            System.out.println(data);
        });
    }
    public static String serialize(List<String> dataList) {

        StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder("<root>");
        dataList.forEach((data) -> {
            xmlBuilder.append("<data>").append(data).append("</data>");
        });
        return xmlBuilder.append("</root>").toString();
    }

    public static List<String> deserialize(String xml) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        final Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        final XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//data/text()");
        final NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        final List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
            dataList.add(nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: If Data contain xml tags this will not work e.g if string is "xx<data>xx", this will create invalid XML. Better encode data value may be with base64 etc to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException;

    public class ArrayListSerializationTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        List dataList = new ArrayList();
        dataList.add("A");
        dataList.add(",");
        dataList.add("B");
        String datStr = serialize(dataList);
        List receivedList = deserialize(datStr);
        for (String string : receivedList) {
          System.out.println(string);
        }
      }

      public static String serialize(List dataList) {

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo)) {
          so.writeObject(dataList);
          so.flush();
          return Base64.encodeBase64String(bo.toByteArray());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
      }

      public static ArrayList deserialize(String dataStr) {

        byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64(dataStr);
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        ObjectInputStream si;
        try {
          si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
          return ArrayList.class.cast(si.readObject());
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
          throw new SerializationException("Error during deserialization", e);
        }
      }
    }
```

This works for your ArrayList example. You can use generics to make the methods more flexible.

Comment: Here we are using apache commons we don't  want this

Comment: @SrinuBabu the jdk also provides Base64 encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

*we dont want any split delimiter because the List may contain any character so there is no possibility to string split*

I disagree!  Here's an approach to dynamically determine the delimiter.  The delimiter cannot start with a number, and the delimiter length and its value are added to the beginning of the string:

```
public class StringsTest {
    private static final int LIST_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int STRING_SIZE = 50;
    private static final Random RAND = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> original = getStrings();
        String encoded = serialize(original);
        List<String> decoded = deserialize(encoded);
        System.out.println(decoded.equals(original));
    }

    private static List<String> deserialize(String encoded) {
        int delimiterSize = Integer.parseInt(encoded.replaceAll("\\D.*", ""));
        int fromIndex =  String.valueOf(delimiterSize).length();
        String delimiter = encoded.substring(fromIndex, fromIndex + delimiterSize);

        String[] splitStrings = encoded.split(delimiter);
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < splitStrings.length; i++) {
            strings.add(splitStrings[i]);
        }

        return strings;
    }

    private static String serialize(List<String> strings) {
        String delimiter = getDelimiter(strings);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(delimiter.length());
        sb.append(delimiter);
        for (String s : strings) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append(delimiter);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String getDelimiter(List<String> strings) {
        String delimiter = getRandomLetter();
        while (isDelimiterInAnyString(strings, delimiter)) {
            delimiter += getRandomLetter();
        }

        return delimiter;
    }

    private static boolean isDelimiterInAnyString(List<String> strings, String delimiter) {
        for (String s : strings) {
            if (s.contains(delimiter)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static String getRandomLetter() {
        return Character.toString((char)( RAND.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
    }

    private static List<String> getStrings() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
            strings.add(getRandomString());
        }

        return strings;
    }

    private static String getRandomString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE; i++) {
            sb.append(getRandomLetter());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a no brainer way and a Leetcode way :D The Leetcode way is for those wheel invention fans.

Let's define a test string array first:

```
ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add("string1");
testList.add("string2");
testList.add("string3");
```

The no briainer way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
new ObjectOutputStream(new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException { sb.append((char)i); }
}).writeObject(testList);

// sb.toString(); <<--- here you get what you want
```

Let's take a quick look at what's in the serialized string:

```
ﾬ￭ sr java.util.ArrayListxﾁￒﾙￇaﾝ I sizexp   w   t string1t string2t string3x
```

It's not hard to guess what it is. If your system doesn't have any restriction to the content of strings, it is what you want.

For deserialization, you can do this:

```
// suppose we are still using the 'sb' from the previous code snippet. it can also be loaded from anywhere else.

final int[] index = {0}; // I hate this, but no way to walk around
ArrayList<String> deserializedList = (ArrayList<String>) new ObjectInputStream(new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException { return sb.charAt(index[0]++); }
}).readObject();
```

The major advantage of the above approach is that it works for all serializable objects, not limited to strings, while the disadvantage is you have less control of what/how the programme is doing it and the serialized content may contain something unsupported by your system.

In terms of the Leetcode way, you have to write your own de/serialization methods. To serialize strings, you do 2 things:

1. Escape: replace all '\' and ';' in the input string with '\\' and '\;'
2. Concatenate: simply chain all escaped input strings together

To deserialize it, you do something like the following:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean esc = false;
// suppose 'inStr' is the serialized input string
for(char c : inStr.toCharArray()) {
    if(esc) {
        s.append(c);
        esc = false;
    } else if(c == '\\') {
        esc = true;
    } else if(c == ';') {
        result.add(sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0);
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}

// this isn't necessary if, by some way, you ensure the input string to be ended with ';'    
if(sb.length() > 0)
    result.add(sb.toString());
```

This way is clear and efficient enough, but as you see it, it works for strings only.

Hope it helps in some extent.